# jQuery .live('click') not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to setup the below `emblem-important.png` so when you click this item, it'll ignore the parent element with `.editable`'s listener and only use the one I've assigned it.  The below code works great in Chrome, but not IE 8.  It's not working in IE 8 and I need it to.  Without using onClick() I'm not sure the best way to set this up in IE 8.  It'd be much easier if I could just set it up with listeners in JS...

```html
<div class="cell editable" style="float:left;width:99%; font-weight:bold; font-size:16pt; padding-bottom:50px" data-fieldid="684709" data-fieldname="Product Name">
     <span id="sob_form_span_684709"><strong>Freedom Communications: Choice PPO</strong><img src="/img/emblem-important.png"></span>
</div>
```

```js
//toggle the form status
jQuery('#formStatus').change(function () {
    jQuery.get('/products/ajax_updateStatus/'+Page.formId+'/'+jQuery(this).val()+'/', {}, function () {
        notify('check', 'Status has been updated');
    });
});

jQuery('.editable').live('click', function () {
    var urlPieces = (document.location+'').split('/');
    jQuery.fancybox({
        'href': urlPieces[0]+'/'+urlPieces[1]+'/'+urlPieces[2]+'/'+urlPieces[3]+'/update_form_field/'+jQuery(this).attr('data-fieldId'),
        'title': jQuery(this).attr('data-fieldName'),
        'autoDimensions': false,
        'margin': 0,
        'padding': 15,
        'width': '768',
        'scrolling': 'auto',
        'height': jQuery(window).height() - 100,
        'onComplete': function() {
            jQuery("#fancybox-title").css({
                'top':'-10px',
                'bottom':'auto'
            });
        }
    });
});

jQuery('img[src=/img/emblem-important.png]').live('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to restore this field to its original content?')) {
        var locSplit = (document.location+'').split('/'),
            id = jQuery(jQuery(e.currentTarget).parent()).attr('id'),
            fieldId = jQuery(this).closest('td').attr('data-fieldId');
        jQuery.get('/customs/revertField/'+locSplit[locSplit.length-1]+'/'+fieldId, function (r) {
            jQuery('#'+id).html(r.fieldValue);
        }, 'json');
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do `id = jQuery(jQuery(e.currentTarget).parent()).attr('id')`, when you could just do `id = this.parentNode.id`?

Comment: Some of the problems would be solved by using .delegate() instead of .live(). Depending on where the event propagates to, you can usually stop propagation successfully on a delegated handler instead of having to return false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some browsers will expand the `src` attribute to the URL actually used to request the image.

Using the [attribute ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) should fix that:

```
img[src$=/img/emblem-important.png]
```

Comment: He's using ".live()"; will "stopPropagation()" have any useful effect?

Comment: (Checked the jQuery source but it's not clear to me from a quick skim of the "live()" code.)

Comment: @Pointy: No, it won't. Instead he should use `return false;` as described under Caveats: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 1):

Won't `return false` do the trick nicely ?

Cf. Jquery doc :

> To stop further handlers from executing after one bound using .live(),
>   the handler must return false. Calling .stopPropagation() will not
>   accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make much sense to call "stopPropagation()" on an event  when using ".live()" to handle it. By the time your handler is called, the event has already propagated all the way up to the body tag.

Instead of doing that, you could simply check the event target and ignore it when appropriate:

```
if ($(event.target).is('img[src=/img/emblem-important.png]'))
  return; // or whatever
```

The "live" mechanism works by using a framework-supplied event handler on the `<body>` element. When that handler gets the event, it looks through the manifest of registered handler selectors and applies each of those when the target matches.

*edit* — <strike>you could also try "event.stopImmediatePropagation()" instead.</strike> *edit again* nope :-) however returning `false` is apparently documented as working.

Comment: `.stopPropagation()` will work *among* handlers bound via `.live()`. [Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/AjCmE/)

Comment: ...nevermind, I think I'm wrong ...clearly I'm wrong, and was very, very confused.

Comment: ...oh wait, I see what the issue was. It does seem to make a difference including `e.stopPropagation()`. http://jsfiddle.net/AjCmE/

Comment: OK - it wasn't exactly clear to me that the ".live()" code paid attention, but I guess it does. I can't tell whether it's dependent on the order the handlers were added; it calls ".closest()" from the target to find handlers to call, but .... well it's confusing.

Comment: It *is* confusing, especially since the docs include the caveat noted in another answer. So I guess my I'm saying that I just have no idea! ;)